# Element Visible on the page but shows null

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, selenium, webdriver

Not able to identify the element in a page.It gives null.I want to identify the element in the Iframe (textbox) .I used selenium webdriver to click on the element,but it is not able to identify the element

1) My HTML Code is as shown bellow

```
      <html>
        <head>
         <body>
         <iframe id="iframeOne">                  
             </iframe>
         </body>    
          </head>

              </html>
```

2.  I used javascript to identify the textbox like document.getElementById('textbox').
But it return null.

3.I even Tried using selenium webdriver

```
  IWebElement ClickElement = Wait.Until((d) => webDriver.FindElement(By.Id(parameter1))); It gives object reference error
            ClickElement.Click();
```

Comment: there are no proper ending tags

Comment: I just gave a rough mark up of the html code Above..Just a sample.. But the html code has proper opening and closing tag.

Comment: I recommend you to learn HTML, not to ask. And **please** accept some answers, your answer rate is just 53%, noone is willing to help you if your rate is low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The html code you put **inside** the iframe tag will be loaded and visible if and only if the browser **does not** support iframe tag. So probably never, unless you're using older Netscape navigator or IE 4.

Add `src` attribute to the iframe pointing to the url you want to load. Then you can access elements inside this way:

```
var frame = document.getElementById('iframeOne');
var frameDocument = frame.contentDocument;
var element = frameDocument.getElementById('xxxx');
```

There's one thing to take into account, though: accesing `contentDocument` when iframe's src is cross-domain might not work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot put html inside an iframe tag. it is to load another page inside the curent page. and your input tag should caontain the type of the control. and check the HTML validation errors.

Comment: Its just a example ..But my real source code has a control type and other things.

Comment: so why don't you put real code here. you want us to guess your code and recreate the issue?